# AuthorizeAttribute does not work on ApiController inside Area

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, azure-web-app-service

A few days ago, half of our Azure hosted ASP.NET Web API (.NET Framework) started playing up.  It's been running fine for a number of months, then all of a sudden, customers couldn't log into one of our front end sites.

We have three applications that connect to the Web API.  Two of them connect through the controllers in the top level Controllers folder, and one of them connects through the controllers inside an Area.  It's this Area that is causing us pain.

```
public class MyAppAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName => "MyApp";

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute("MyAppApi", "myapp/api/{controller}/{action}");
    }
}
```

Both parts of the Web API use the same code to generate Jwt Security Tokens, and unauthorized methods in both areas are okay.

```
private JwtSecurityToken GenerateSecurityToken(int userId, string username, int customerId)
{
    var signingKey = GetSigningKey();
    var audience = GetSiteUrl(); // Must match the url of the site
    var issuer = GetSiteUrl(); // Must match the url of the site 

    var lifeTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var expiry = now.Add(lifeTime);

    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userId.ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, username),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Prn, customerId.ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, now.Ticks.ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, expiry.Ticks.ToString())
    };

    var token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(claims, signingKey, audience, issuer, lifeTime);

    return token;
}
```

After much effort trying to work out what could have changed, we implemented a CustomAuthorizeAttribute and applied it to a controller inside the Area and a controller outside the Area.  The one **outside** the Area appears to have the *actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity* set correctly, but the one **inside** the area is empty.  Not null.  Just empty.  We logged both the *actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal* as well as the *Thread.CurrentPrincipal*, but both are empty.

I can't seem to work out what is responsible for managing this data, and why it now refuses to do it for controllers with the area.

I'm able to access the token and extract the claims successfully.

All help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I think this kind of problem should not be solved in the forum, if you do not provide more error information.

Comment: Because your code has been running very well in the past few months, I think it is possible that there is a problem with the version control, and whether there is a mistake when a member updates the code. It is recommended to roll back the program to the last working version, or update the backup program to use.

Comment: If you have a version control tool, you can check the latest check-in and check-out information, or version update information. It is recommended to republish your web program in the test environment after checking that there is no problem, and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Hi Jason.  There is no error and therefore no error information.  The request fails authorization because the Identity is empty.  Just like it would if I tried hitting any authorized method without authenticating first.

Comment: The version that is deployed IS the last working version.  It's been fine for months.  We did no changes to the site at all.  No deployments, no configuration changes.

Comment: According to your statement, we can be sure that there is no problem with the procedure, right. Therefore, the program that can run normally has been running for a period of time, and there is a failure without any error message. I [suggest to raise a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) and let Microsoft engineers check the background running log.